# VectorTile stops trying to load tiles

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to host vector tiles on my local machine but I'm not allowed to run a tile server.  So I unpacked an mbtiles database filled with pbf files and I'm accessing them directly with the following VectorTile layer.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            tileSize: 512,
            minZoom: 4,
            maxZoom: 18,
        }),
        tilePixelRatio: 8,
        //url: 'http://localhost:2020/foo/bar/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
        url: 'file://C:/ProgramData/foo/bar/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
    }),
    renderMode: 'vector'
});
```

All is good unless I navigate to a place in the world where tiles don't exist.   The VectorTile source stops trying to load more tiles.  It won't even try when I navigate back to a place where I know tiles exist.

How can I make the VectorTile source not give up so easily?

**UPDATE:**
I modified the code snippet to show the two URLs I've been using.  Both are using the same data set.  The first url is being served by Caddy and everything is great.  The second url is the browser accessing the files directly which works great until I go where tiles don't exist.

Comment: Can you put up a codepen that shows the behavior? It might be a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can show this behavior since it depends on missing tiles on a local disk.  I'm open to suggestions.